# Referencing a field from Event in Computed Fields

Tags: nodes, entities, datetime

Background: I am creating a task list for hosting events. The list is the same for each event only the date of the event will change. The due date of each task is based on the event date minus the number of days before it must be completed. (ex. Task 1 is due 5 days before Event so if Event is 7/30/15, Task 1 is due 7/25/15)

I am referencing a date field from an Event node. I am trying to calculate a due date for multiple tasks based on the Event date in Open Atrium. I have used "Field Reference" to get the date which displays on the task. When I try to reference the field in computed fields it does not display. When you do a Field Reference, does it save the information differently than a field that is created at the node?

I have tried to reference the referenced field using these two methods without any luck.

$events_date = array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_event_date');

$event_date = $entity->field_event_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];

Also if there is a better way to solve this problem please let me know.